# GRANT ALTER ON TABLE DB_Name.Schema_name.Table_name TO ROLE Role_name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

GRANT ALTER ON TABLE EDPINT_DEV.EDP_RAW.EDP_INGRESS_PARM TO ROLE EDPINT_DEV_ADMIN_SUPPORT;

in snowflake
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 6 Invalid privilege ALTER.

Comment: [Table Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#table-privileges)

Comment: There's no ALTER privilege on tables. Check the link provided by @LukaszSzozda

Answer (score 0):

Please check the grant option here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

To grant privilege to a table, here are the valid options:

schemaObjectPrivileges ::=
-- For TABLE
{ SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES } [ , ... ]

So in your case you would want to use UPDATE like so:

GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE EDPINT_DEV.EDP_RAW.EDP_INGRESS_PARM TO ROLE EDPINT_DEV_ADMIN_SUPPORT;